# Modifying JavaFX Scene Loaded via FXML File?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm attempting to modify a JavaFX scene, loaded via a FXML file, in the Java code of the application I'm running.

I have the following test FXML file, created with SceneBuilder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="" xmlns:fx="">
   <top>
      <TabPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab text="Untitled Tab 2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </top>
   <center>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Which is just a `BorderPane` with two empty tabs in the `Top` section, and an empty `Center` section. I wish to be able to draw some shapes in the `Center` section. I took [the following example code](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/canvas/jfxpub-canvas.htm) for drawing some random shapes in a `Canvas` window, and made sure the example code works by-itself:

[image]

I then wanted to insert that same exact drawn `Canvas`, with the exact same shapes, into the `Center` section of my `BorderPane` declared in the FXML file shown above.

However, I'm a bit confused as to how I'm supposed to properly reference the various children of the scene loaded by the FXML loader. If I try the following code in my `start` function:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException 
{
    stage.setTitle("Drawing Operations Test");
    Scene scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 1280, 720);
        
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    drawShapes(gc);
    scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getChildren().add(canvas);
        
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Where `drawShapes` is the function that draws the shapes on the `Canvas`, the line:

```
scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getChildren().add(canvas);
```

Is listed as erroneous, because the class-function `getChildren` cannot be found in the `Node` class.

Now, my initial assumption for the cause of that error was because I'm supposed to typecast the `Node` object into the respective class that I'm wanting to add `canvas` to, in my case the `BorderPane` class. However, I wanted to clarify exactly what the `getChildren` class-function will return me here.

Does `getChildren` return the `BorderPane` object, as that's the first object that's declared in the FXML file? Or is that element parented under something else? What would be the proper way of adding my `Canvas` to the `Center` section of my `BorderPane`?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scene.getRoot()
```

will return the root of the scene, which you set via the call to the `Scene` constructor:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 1280, 720);
```

In other words, `scene.getRoot()` is the object returned from `load.FXML(...)`. You haven't shown us that method definition, so we cannot know for sure, but it is reasonable to assume it returns the result of calling `FXMLLoader.load(...)`, which would be the `BorderPane` (the root element, in the XML sense, of the FXML file).

So you could cast the result of `scene.getRoot()` to a `BorderPane` and then call `setCenter(...)` (or, obviously better, just keep a reference to the result of `loadFXML(...)` in the first place).

The code

```
scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable()
```

will return a list of the child nodes of the `BorderPane`, i.e. a list containing just the `TabPane`, and so

```
scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0)
```

is a reference to the `TabPane`, and

```
scene.getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(0).getChildren()
```

(with appropriate casts added) is a list of the child nodes of the `TabPane`. The content of that list is basically an implementation detail of the `TabPane` and its skin.

---

None of this is the way the API designers intended this to be used, though. Instead, define a [controller class](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) for the FXML, and inject the `BorderPane` into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Line?>


<BorderPane 
    maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
    minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" 
    prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" 
    xmlns="" xmlns:fx=""
    fx:controller="my.package.MyController"
    fx:id="borderPane" 
>

    <!-- ... -->

</BorderPane>
```

Then define the controller, and modify the border pane in the `initialize()` method (if you want to add the canvas immediately), or in an event handler (if you want to modify the scene graph in response to user actions):

```
package my.package;

// imports ...

public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(300, 250);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawShapes(gc);
        borderPane.setCenter(canvas);

    }

    private void drawShapes(GraphicsContext gc) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. The first solution appeared to work well for me, and I'm able to draw `canvas` inside the `Center` section of my `BorderPane`. However, I wish to learn more about the proper, second method you described, using the controller for the `BorderPane` object. I already have a controller for the `App` class that I'm running this program off of, however I'm unsure how to set another controller for just the `BorderPane` object here. In the SceneBuilder, with which I built the FXML file, I can't see a `Controller` property I can edit... Where is that in the SceneBuilder?

Comment: @Runsva In the bottom left is a "controller" section you can expand. If you select a component (e.g. the `BorderPane`), then the bottom right has a "Code" section you can expand, and there is an `fx:id` field there. Note the controller class is a property of the FXML file, not of an individual component. I recommend reading the documentation I linked in the answer. (Or really any tutorial on FXML will explain this.)